# Issue Creating Translation Workflow in SDL Web

Tags: workflow, web8, translation-manager

I am trying to create a Translation Workflow in Web8 when I attempt to Save the Process Definition from Visio to the Content Manager I get the following error message

> Invalid value for property 'ActivityDefinitions'. Activity 'RETRIEVE'
>   has invalid script. L2: Unexpected character: =

The script looks fine to me so what am I missing. The script is as follows:

```
`// Script for Automatic Activity Content Manager Workflow
ActivityFinishData finishData = new ActivityFinishData() { Message = "Automatic Activity Finished" };
SessionAwareCoreServiceClient.FinishActivity(CurrentActivityInstance.Id, finishData, null);`
```

I have Visio Premium 2010 SP2 installed

The Script Type is "*Translation Manager activity*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script must be a single keyword. So replace the three lines you have (the comment and the two C# lines) with a single keyword:
`RETRIEVE`

It is this keyword in the script Translation Manager will pick up, not the title of your activity.

Comment: Ahah, you made it _too_ simple :)

Comment: Don't worry, I know how to fix that! :)